# Find the roots of 2 equations

Tags: roots, exponential-function

Show that the equation $e^{-x} = x^2$ has a root between $x=0.70$ and $x=0.71$.

I think you have to use natural logs to get rid of the $e$ however after that, i'm not sure how to solve for $x$

Comment: There's no $x$ in the '$e$ side' of the equation, so there's no need to get rid of anything. It's the same basic idea as solving $x^2 = A$ for any other number $A$. Now follow Cameron Buie's hint below.

Comment: Are you sure this is the right question, because that equation has no roots in the interval given (the roots are $\pm \frac{1}{e}$).

Comment: sorry the question i typed in earlier was incorrect. the question is e^-x = x^2

Comment: Or was it $e^{-x}=x^{-e}$ with root between $2.70$ and $2.72$ ?

Comment: no, it is as stated above

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $f(x)=e^{-x}-x^2$ is continuous, and $f(0.70)>0>f(0.71),$ so....

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way. Let $f(x) = e^{-x} - x^2$.

Note that $f(0.70) >0$ and $f(0.71) <0$. Hence since the conditions of the intermediate value theorem apply, we must have $x \in (0.70,0.71)$ such that $f(x) = 0$.

If you prefer, you could take logs to get the equation $-x = 2 \ln x$. Then let $g(x) = x+2 \ln x$ and note that $g(0.70)<0$ and $g(0.71)>0$.

Comment: Hmm, the 'answered' time stamp makes it look like I copied Cameron's answer, however the non-so-visible edit trail will show that this is not the case...

Answer (score 0):

I have found how to solve this question.
Since the equation has a root, means it crosses the x axis and goes to either the + or - side of the y axis. Therefore to show it has a root between 0.71 and 0.70, we substitute each of the values into the equation and show that the answers has different signs.